# What's the most elegant way to accomplish this control flow in Python?

Tags: python

Newer coder here; sorry if this question is extremely basic.

Let's say I have a function like this:

```
def foo(a=True, b=False):
    for i in range(1000000000):
        if a:
            obfuscate()
        if b:
            frobnicate()
```

This is obviously inefficient because I evaluate the if statement conditions on each iteration through the for loop. What's a more elegant way to accomplish the same thing?

EDIT: I think that I glossed over too much of the detail when I tried to minimalize my example. There are multiple interdependencies that I didn't capture here. Anyone not already involved in the discussion should probably steer clear.

Comment: Are `a` and `b` vectors? Your  example is not clear.

Comment: it all depends on what <do something> is... [mcve]

Comment: The cost of evaluating the `if` condition is trivial. This is not where you should be directing your optimization efforts.

Comment: Is `do something` the same each time or does it use `i` in some way?

Comment: I apologize for the poorly presented example. I'm going back to edit it now.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, you don't indicate that `a` or `b` ever change. So you can determine which functions are going to be invoked before you begin to loop:

```
def foo(a=True, b=False):
    for i in range(1000000):
        if a:
            obfuscate()
        if b:
            frobnicate()
```

Becomes:

```
def foo(a=True, b=False):
    action = None

    if a and b:
        def f():
            obfuscate()
            frobnicate()

        action = f

    elif a:
        action = obfuscate

    elif b:
        action = frobnicate

    else:
        return  # Loop won't call any functions, skip it.

    for i in range(1000000):
        action()
```

I assume that by `1000000` you mean "a lot of times." (Which 1M isn't, actually, on modern hardware.) If so, you might want to actually split out the `a and b` case into a separate code line that just calls the two functions, saving you some opcodes for making the calls:

```
if a and b:
    for i in range(1000000):
        obfuscate()
        frobnicate()
    return
elif ...
```

Comment: Heh, I am failing so hard at posing this question properly. The function in question get called many, many times - enough so that running my program takes minutes. When I used 1000 in my original example, people told me that optimizing if statements wasn't worth my time. I was trying to emphasize the fact that it might be worth my time but I didn't want to write out an absurdly long number. 10^6 seemed liked an okay compromise.

Comment: I assumed you meant "a lot", which is fine. It's ironic that people will say "Provide a minimal example" and then say, "That code is trivial!" ;-)

Comment: @AustinHastings It's not the code that's trivial. If you have a loop that's running millions of times, if clauses are probably the last thing you should optimize.

Comment: Also, it's worth pointing out that this function *probably* isn't your bottleneck if the `obfuscate` or `frobnicate` actions are non-trivial. After you get this restructured, search for "profiling" python. There are modules that can help figure out where your time is spent.

Comment: @ayhan Totally fair. I'm still looking for an answer to the question, though. I feel like this is something that I should be able to accomplish without much effort but I'm not sure how to do it properly.

Comment: @B.Ripman Can you provide more context? What's calling this function? What are the two lower-level functions doing? Also, do they have to be called in the alternating sequence?

Comment: @AustinHastings Reposting: the code is a lot more complicated than this. I think that I managed to lose some of the important details in my effort to minimalize my example. The function is actually passed a list of objects and runs a while loop to perform a bunch of actions while the list isn't empty. On each iteration through the while loop it pops out some number of objects from the list, performs some complicated actions, and then decides which of their class methods to run based on the true/false value of boolean arguments a and b (which do not change within the function).

Comment: Definitely profile it, then. See here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that either a or b will occur in each iteration, in that case replace `if b:` with `elif b:`. that way if it is a, it doesn't check for b.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I clearly should have written my example this way since this is what most people are seizing on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any inefficiencies with the code you have written. This runtime is `O(n)` and is suitable for most cases where you have to go through a list. One suggestion, however, is that you should use `elif` when checking if `i` fits `b`'s case. As follows:

```
def foo(a, b):
    for i in range(1000):
        <do things>
        if a:
            <do something>
        elif b:
            <do something slightly different>
```

**Edit**: If a and b are fixed parameters, this would work:

```
def foo(a, b):
    l = [i for i in range(1000)]
    if a:
        funcA(l)
    elif b:
        funcB(l)
```

Comment: My apologies for not making this clear in the original example (which I have edited). a and b are arguments of this function; they will always have the same value in each iteration of the for loop.

I do understand that elif reduces the computational overhead but I figured it would add unneeded complication to the example. :)

Comment: I made an edit to my answer. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

assuming the semantic is ok (i do not know whether "*thing" has any side effect or no, nor whether there are any kind of data dependency or not), then you can move the `if` (loop invariant) outside of the loop

```
def foo(a, b):
    for i in range(1000):
        <do things>
    if a:
        for i in range(1000):
            <do something>
    if b:
        for i in range(1000):
            <do something slightly different>
```

Generally speaking, compilers are good at moving loop invariants outside a loop.

Since you are using python, i guess performance is not your number one priority, so i'd rather suggest you stick with your initial version which is more readable, and let the compiler/interpreter do their magic and optimize this for you under the hood.

Comment: This is going to be variant-dependent. CPython, for example, can't even spell optimization.

Comment: The code is a lot more complicated than this. I think that I managed to lose some of the important details in my effort to minimalize my example.

The function is actually passed a list of objects and runs a while loop to perform a bunch of actions while the list isn't empty. On each iteration through the while loop it pops out some number of objects from the list, performs some complicated actions, and then decides which of their class methods to run based on the true/false value of boolean arguments a and b (which do not change within the function).

Answer (score -2):

You might want to use elif instead of the second if as the condition in else is only executed if a is false. In addition to that optimization of code usually deals with optimization of loops runtime. If condition does not have such large impact on optimization.

```
def foo(a=True, b=False):
    for i in range(1000000):
        if a:
            obfuscate()
        elif b:
            frobnicate()
```